# Quantiles for non-normal cdf

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

When I compute the five-number summary on my sample, I obtain quantiles that differ from the quantiles I got from the empirical cdf, since they are not normally distributed data.

Can you help me in the interpretation of this difference?

For instance, with a randomly-generated Poisson dataset x

```
x=rpois(50, 2)
summary(x)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.00    1.00    1.50    1.82    2.75    6.00 
y=ecdf(x)
summary(y)
Empirical CDF:    7 unique values with summary
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.0     1.5     3.0     3.0     4.5     6.0
```

What does it mean that the 3rd quantile of the sample is `2.75` while it is `4.5` for the ecdf?

Comment: The second summary is `summary(0:6)`, that is, the summary of the unique values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with being non-normal.

`summary(x)` is computing sample quantiles of your data, using type 7 quantiles (see `help(quantile)` in R for the various quantile types).

I'm guessing that you've used `summary(y)` to produce the second set of values. In that case, the results are probably not what you want as they are giving you quantiles of the data set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, the step points of the empirical cdf.

You can get the quantiles from the ecdf object using `quantile(y)` which should give you the same results as `quantile(x)`.

Comment: thanks Rob! I see the point now. However the quantile function does not work on ecdf, quantile(y) gives error. How can I retrieve the quantiles from the ecdf then?

Comment: It works for me.