# Have doubt in Summary function R?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

I have vector $x=[3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 18, 21]$ and  wanted to see summary 
 statistics.

if I use `summary(x)` function in R, My anwser

```
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   3.00    7.00   12.00   11.22   14.00   21.00
```

But actual anwser is Q1 = 6 and Q2=16

What is the difference ?

Comment: See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134229/28500) among others on this site for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is ordered and has $N = 9$.

The median is the element of position $(N + 1) / 2 = 5$, i.e. $12$.

The half samples $\{3,\, 5,\, 7,\, 8,\, 12\}$ and $\{12,\, 13,\, 14,\, 18,\, 21\}$ have $n = 5$.

The median of the half samples, i.e. $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ of `x`, are the elements of position $(n + 1) / 2 = 3$, i.e. $7$ and $14$, as returned by `sample(x)`.

Comment: x<-c(1,2,3,4,4,5)
> summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.250   3.500   3.167   4.000   5.000   In this case  how it works please explain? @ocram

Comment: Please type `help(quantile)` at the `R` console and see the different approaches to that problem, that `R` has to offer. The heading "Types" is the most relevant one.