# How do you determine the 1st quartile? Answer differing from what R outputs

Tags: r, quantiles

I get that the definition of the first quartile is the value of the data set in which it is greater than 25% of the data set; below I have defined a vector in R (which is already ordered)

```r
datold = c(12,
32, 32, 32, 32, 32,
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42)
```

Notice that this set of data is already ordered from lowest to greatest and there are 26 elements in this data set; since the 1st quartile is the 25th percentile, I take 26/4, which is 6.5. In order to find the 1st quartile now, would it not be correct to take the average of the 6th and 7th value? That being $(32+35)/2 = 33.5$?

The value that R outputs when you do `summary(datold)` is `35`. I'm just trying to understand the error in my understanding; any help would be appreciated.

Just editing in to add that the question from the textbook asks what the IQR of the data set is (and the answer provided was 3 which I assume they got from 38-35).

Comment: Please tell us the textbook. On the face of it asking for the IQR when there are just four distinct values is ignoring a detail that should not.be ignored!

Comment: Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24112, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134229, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There is no one single correct method to evaluate quartiles: any method generally would involve linear interpolation between two order statistics, with weights defined according to the working principle used, if I need to frame this in a very loose yet simple language.

Using `quantile()` yields

```r
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
12.0 35.0 36.5 38.0 42.0
```

But what is actually happening is $\mathtt R$ is employing type $7$ linear interpolation to evaluate the quantiles.

```r
> quantile(x, type = 7)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
12.0 35.0 36.5 38.0 42.0
```

If you use type $4$ linear interpolation, you would get

```r
> quantile(x, type = 4)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
12.0 33.5 35.0 38.0 42.0
```

If you need more details as to what is transpiring behind those methods, I can readily expand, but that would be based primarily on the [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684934) by [Hyndman and Fan](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman) on this.

Comment: +1. Note that the Hyndman paper is explicitly referenced in the `?quantile` help page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @StephanKolassa.